# Como crear variables de compilacion dinamicas en Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic, compilador

**El Problema:**
Hola buenas, actualmente tengo un proyecto en Angular 10, el cual se compila para diferentes companys en sus propios servidores con sus variables personalizadas.
Es decir tienen su:

```
export const environment = {
  API_URL:'https://server-company.com'
};
```

La variable API_URL debe ser una constante distinta por company, ya que es compilada explícitamente para cada cliente por separado.

**La solucion ideal:**
Quisiera saber si exite alguna forma de enviar variables por el comando de compilación, ejemplo:
`ng build --prod -var API_URL="https://cosa.com"`
Ya que seria un gran problema editar el proyecto por cada company que se subscriba

Comment: En Angular puede ejecutar el siguiente comando: ng build --configuration="entorno"
, estos entorno los creas en el archivo angular.json

Comment: pues... ten en cuenta que aunque environment sea una constante, como se trata de un objeto tu no puedes cambiar el objeto, pero si que puedes cambiar el contenido del objeto, por lo tanto lo unico que tienes que hacer es detectar que cambios necesitas hacerle a la `URL` desde el codigo y apartir del mismo codigo cambiar los valores de las propiedades que necesites en ese objeto, pues pasa algo curioso con los arrays y los objetos, y es que ninguno puede cambiar de puntero pero los espacios en memoria de ambos si que pueden ser modificados.

Comment: mirate esto creo que es lo que buscas https://medium.com/@ferie/how-to-pass-environment-variables-at-building-time-in-an-angular-application-using-env-files-4ae1a80383c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Traducido y resumido de [este post](https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/)

---

Es posible lograrlo simulando un enviroment de la siguiente manera:

1. Creas un archivo llamado `env.js` con la siguiente estructura (no con `cli`) a la misma altura que el `index.html`

```
(function (window) {
  window.__env = window.__env || {};

  // API url
  window.__env.apiUrl = 'http://dev.your-api.com';

  // Whether or not to enable debug mode
  // Setting this to false will disable console output
  window.__env.enableDebug = true;
}(this));
```

Esto creara una variable global `__env` en el navegador conteniendo las variables de ambiente (enviroment)  para nuestra aplicación.

2. Agregamos una etiqueta `<script>` al elemento `<head>` en nuestro `indexh.html` para cargar `env.js` antes de que angular sea cargado.

```
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <!-- Cargar variables de ambiente -->
    <script src="env.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    ...
    <!-- El código de Angular se carga aquí -->
  </body>  

</html>
```

3. Le decimos a angular que al hacer `ng build` incluya este archivo:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "app-name": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/env.js" // <= Agregamos aqui nuestro fichero
            ]
          }
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              // ...
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

4. Notificamos a angular de este nuevo archivo generando un servicio que cargue las variables en el scope de angular:

`$ ng generate service env`

Y reemplazamos el contenido:

```
export class EnvService {
  // Los valores que sean definidos aqui son los valores por defecto
  // que pueden ser sobreescritos por evn.js

  // API url
  public apiUrl = '';

  // Habilitar o no el modo debug. 
  public enableDebug = true;

  constructor() {
  }

}
```

5. Creamos un nuevo fichero manualmente llamado `env.service.provider.ts` en el mismo directorio del servicio que contenga lo siguiente:

```
import { EnvService } from './env.service';

export const EnvServiceFactory = () => {  
  // Creamos el ambiente
  const env = new EnvService();
  // Leemos las variables de ambiente desde la ventana del navegador
  const browserWindow = window || {};
  const browserWindowEnv = browserWindow['__env'] || {};
  
  // Asignamos las variables de ambiente desde el navegador hacia env
  // En la implementacion actual, las propiedades de env.js sobreescriben los
  // valores por default en el EnvService
  // Si lo necesitas, aquí se puede realizar una fusión profunda para fusionar propiedades en lugar de sobrescribirlas

  for (const key in browserWindowEnv) {
    if (browserWindowEnv.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      env[key] = window['__env'][key];
    }
  }

  return env;
};

export const EnvServiceProvider = {  
  provide: EnvService, //Importamos este servicio definido con anterioridad
  useFactory: EnvServiceFactory, //Exportamos el factory que crea la instancia de EnvService y copia los valores del objeto `window.__env` en la instancia de EnvService
  deps: [],
};
```

6. Agregamos `EnvServiceProvider` a los `providers` para usar la inyección de dependencias de angular de esta manera:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';  
import { EnvServiceProvider } from './env.service.provider';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ // ... ],
  providers: [EnvServiceProvider],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Con estos pasos deberías de ser capaz de acceder a los datos en el fichero `env.js` y modificarlos aun con tu código compilado.

## Ejemplo de uso:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';  
import { EnvService } from '../env.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent {  
  constructor(
    private env: EnvService
  ) {
    if(env.enableDebug) {
      console.log('Debug mode enabled!');
    }
  }
}
```

Cabe señalar que en el link que te pongo hace una demostración sobre cómo es posible modificar el fichero `env.js` directamente en los archivos compilados para lograr lo que tu quieres sin necesidad de volver a compilar.